# What is the expected syntax for checking exception messages in MiniTest's assert_raises/must_raise?

Tags: ruby, tdd, minitest, assertion

What is the expected syntax for checking exception messages in MiniTest's `assert_raises`/`must_raise`?

I'm trying to make an assertion something like the following, where `"Foo"` is the expected error message:

```
proc { bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError.new("Foo")
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3454925/1569

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can use the [`assert_raises`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raises) assertion, or the [`must_raise`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/spec/rdoc/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_raise) expectation.

```
it "must raise" do
  assert_raises RuntimeError do 
    bar.do_it
  end
  ->     { bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError
  lambda { bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError
  proc   { bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError
end
```

If you need to test something on the error object, you can get it from the assertion or expectation like so:

```
describe "testing the error object" do
  it "as an assertion" do
    err = assert_raises RuntimeError { bar.do_it }
    assert_match /Foo/, err.message
  end

  it "as an exception" do
    err = ->{ bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError
    err.message.must_match /Foo/
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool, I get that. However, I'm still lost on how to make an assertion on the raised error's message.

Comment: err = ->{ bar.do_it }.must_raise RuntimeError 
syntax did not work for me, It kept raising the following exception.

NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_raises' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @thanikkal Make sure you are using `Minitest::Spec` and not `Minitest::Test`. The Spec DSL, including expectations, are only available when using `Minitest::Spec`.

Answer (score 39):

To assert exception:

```
assert_raises FooError do
  bar.do_it
end
```

To assert exception message:

As per [API doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raises), `assert_raises` returns the exception matched so you can check the message, attributes, etc.

```
exception = assert_raises FooError do
  bar.do_it
end
assert_equal('Foo', exception.message)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for minitest

Answer (score 8):

Minitest does not provide (yet) you a way to check the actual exception message. But you could add a helper method that does it and extend `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class to use everywhere in your rails test suite, e.g.:
in `test_helper.rb`

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def assert_raises_with_message(exception, msg, &block)
    block.call
  rescue exception => e
    assert_match msg, e.message
  else
    raise "Expected to raise #{exception} w/ message #{msg}, none raised"
  end
end
```

and use it in your tests like:

```
assert_raises_with_message RuntimeError, 'Foo' do
  code_that_raises_RuntimeError_with_Foo_message
end
```

Comment: True that Minitest doesn't support checking the error message, however it can be achieved using `must_raise` because it gives you the instance of the error so you can check the message yourself.

Comment: This solution feels better to me, but I've not used ``must_raise`` before.

Comment: I think that this solution will not fail if no Exception is raisen. You just check raised exception to be the correct one. But if no exception is raised, no assertion is done => no errors.

Comment: good point @Foton I changed the answer to reflect that expectation.

Comment: I was doing this to assert error messages too https://github.com/noraj/nvd_api/blob/cf5127568b274e031d1cba4b1afd6856d8cfbb42/test/test_nvd_feed_api.rb#L54-L74

Answer (score 0):

To add some more recent developments, there have been [some discussions](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/599) on adding `assert_raises_with_message` to minitest in the past without much luck.

Currently, there is a [promising pull request](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/627) waiting to be merged. If and when it gets merged, we will be able to use `assert_raises_with_message` without having to define it ourselves.

In the meanwhile, there is this handy little gem named [minitest-bonus-assertions](https://github.com/halostatue/minitest-bonus-assertions) which defines exactly that method, along with few others, so that you can use it out of the box. See the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest-bonus-assertions/2.0/Minitest/Assertions#assert_raises_with_message-instance_method) for more information.