# NoMethodError: undefined method `RuntimeError' when I use {...} syntax instead of do...end with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm using minitest to test a class with a method that raises an exception. I'm using a technique that is described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418628/what-is-the-expected-syntax-for-checking-exception-messages-in-minitests-assert) but I'm having some confusing results:

code:

```
class Formatter
  def output_report
    raise "Abstract method called: #{__method__}"
  end
end
```

test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'formatter'

class TestFormatter < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @formatter = Formatter.new
  end

  def test_formatter_error_when_abstract_method_called
    err = assert_raises RuntimeError { @formatter.output_report }
    assert_equal "Abstract method called: output_report", err.message
  end
end
```

I was expected the test to pass, except instead I got the following error:

```
Run options: --seed 64742

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.001274s, 784.9294 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
TestFormatter#test_formatter_error_when_abstract_method_called:
NoMethodError: undefined method `RuntimeError' for #<TestFormatter:0x007fd07a2b93d0>
    test_formatter.rb:10:in `test_formatter_error_when_abstract_method_called'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

But then if I use the `do...end` block syntax instead of `{...}` then the test passes

do...end:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'formatter'

class TestFormatter < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @formatter = Formatter.new
  end

  def test_formatter_error_when_abstract_method_called
    # err = assert_raises RuntimeError { @formatter.output_report }
    err = assert_raises RuntimeError do
      @formatter.output_report
    end
    assert_equal "Abstract method called: output_report", err.message
  end
end
```

output:

```
Run options: --seed 37315

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001298s, 770.4160 runs/s, 1540.8321 assertions/s.

1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Why is this happening? I thought `do...end` was equal to `{...}` except it's a convention to use the former when making a multi-line block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a significant difference between `do..end` and `{...}`: the precedence matters. Curlies are greedy, `do...end` are not.

Contrived example:

```
puts [1].each { |i| i }    #⇒ 1
puts [1].each do |i| i end #⇒ #<Enumerator:0x000000067dd678>
```

That said, to make curlies to work as expected, one should use parentheses:

```
assert_raises(RuntimeError) { @formatter.output_report }
```

Comment: I think I get it, so in your first example the curlies are greedy, so the block gets run first. But in the second the `puts` prints the `[1].each` before it has a chance to run the block? And `[1].each` is an object that happens to be an enumerator, which is why we get some enumerator printed? `[1].each.class #=> Enumerator`

Comment: @mbigras: to be more clear, the first is like this: `puts([1].each { |i| i } )`, wheras the second is like this: `puts([1].each) { |i| i }`. In the first case, the block is passed to `each` and executed, and then each returns `[1]` (because each just returns the receiver); in the second case, `[1].each` is evaluated without a block (and returns an Enumerator object), and then the block is passed to `puts` (which ignores it entirely).