# How to test for exceptions in shoulda along with TestUnit?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit, shoulda, padrino

I have an application based on padrinorb and I am using the shoulda testing library for the same. There is a method that I need to test throws exception. I tried finding the documentation for the same, but couldn't find anything.

Here's the sample code that I want to test

```
def some_method(param)
    raise APIException.new('Exception) if param == 2
end
```

How should I test that the some_method throws an exception when passed the parameter 2.

Comment: An aside: To pass your tests, and make the question easier to answer you probably want `param == 2`?

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake there, thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expect{ some_method(params) }.to raise_error(APIException)
```

if you use TestUnit this should work ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454925/rails-activesupport-how-to-assert-that-an-error-is-raised))

```
assert_raises(APIException) { some_method(params) }
```

To test the exception message as well use the following:

```
exception = assert_raises(Exception) { whatever.merge }
assert_equal( "message", exception.message )
```

Comment: Is this a valid shoulda matcher? I was trying to use it and got a method not found "Undefined method expect"

Comment: no it is RSpec https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-6/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: I am actually not using rspec, using shoula over TestUnit, but thanks for you help :-)

Comment: updates answer to test for exception message as well.